# Why @ComponentScan requires nested packages to work

Tags: java, spring

guys. I'm new in spring and face an issue with @ComponentScan annotation. According to the [official spring API](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning), it says @ComponentScan can scan the current package and all subpackages without argument and can scan the specified package and its subpakcages with arguement.

However, when I was practicing by implementing my own mini-program, I found that @ComponentScan can only work with the nested package with or without argument.

I created a project using maven as the build tool, and the structure is shown below.[image]

and the AppConfig is [image]
the App will call Corolla and its marked as Component, I dont give @ComponentScan argument here. I think it should work but give me Exception

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor'

Then I tried to give the argument to @ComponentScan to specify the package

> @ComponentScan("org")

It still didn't work, throwing same exception.

Then I tried to move these three classess into inner package studyhard and change argument to org.studyhard
[image]

it worked as what I expected.
Then I remove argument, it still worked.

Why does @ComponentScan only work when given nested packages such as "org.studyhard" rather than the single one "org"?

Comment: by the way, when it was throwing exceptions, that is, in the org package, IDEA can show me all components in the current packages and sub packages it should have scanned.

Comment: Because you want to limit the scanning to *your* application. There's a plethora of classes in `org.*`, and you're not going to want to scan all of them (that'll bound to result in all kinds of errors).

Comment: I think it's a good habit to have more domains in your demo applications' base package, something like 'com.name.project'